# How to secure WCF service with public / private key pair without using any certificates

Tags: wcf, security

I want to secure my WCF service.

For example if I want to generate public / private key pair without involving any third-party certification authority.

What is the way and method to do it?

Any idea or any other approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can create test certificates using "makecert" commands as shown [**here**](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Use%20Certificate%20Authentication%20and%20Message%20Security%20in%20WCF%20calling%20from%20Windows%20Forms&referringTitle=How%20Tos). You can bypass certificate validation checks using configuration such as below, although this is not recommended in a production environment:

```
<authentication certificateValidationMode="None"
                      revocationMode="NoCheck" />
```

I'd have a good read of the configuration options for different scenarios at this [CodePlex link](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/), it will show you the different security options and how to configure them.

Comment: But i don'nt want to buy certificate in production mode, Does this make sense. Or i need to implement some other way to secure wcf service.

Comment: You can work around it like this so you wouldn't need to buy a cert. The makecert command allows you to generate your own cert and the config prevents validation and checking.

Comment: But on production server will it work.

Can you give any idea so i can implement security using RSA encryption by extention.